# Any tools or library to manipulate CUDA PTX code?

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, gpu

I am wondering if there is something to manipulate PTX, as easily as like LLVM and its library to manipulate LLVM IR.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If you would like to *generate* PTX from IR, then check out the CUDA LLVM Compiler SDK: http://developer.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-llvm-compiler

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean affecting how the compiler generates PTX or a library that tweaks generated PTX? In either case, I don't think any such tools are available.

You can insert inline PTX into a kernel with the `asm` keyword.